# How to change width of a div

Tags: css

My current login pages looks like this

[Mobile size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvyR2.png)
[Desktop size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34uhH.jpg)

I'm happy with my curent desktop sized login page but for my mobile page, I would want to hide the image on the right and have the login part fill up the space.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to work

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 415px) {
  #login .overlay-container {
    display: none;
  }
  #login .log-in-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

#login .log-in-container {
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#login .overlay-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container" style="margin: auto;">
  <div class="form-container log-in-container">
    <form method="POST" action="/customer/login">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <input id="userEmail" type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com" name="email">
      <input id="userPw" type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password">
      <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
      <button type="submit">Log In</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay-container">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZaddCas.jpg"> {{!--
        <h1>HTML CSS Login Form</h1>
        <p>This login form is created using pure HTML and CSS. For social icons, FontAwesome is used.</p> --}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main reason you have this issue is because your "desktop" rules don't seem to be defined within a media-query themselves (unless you're not sharing that part of the CSS).

Hence, your "desktop" rules are always considered because:

- they have the exact same [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) as the "mobile" ones specified in a mediaquery (which doesn't impact specificity)
- they're presumably specified later in your CSS file

So 2 possible solutions (among probably a longer list of possibilities, but these seems to be the simplest ones) :

- Include these "desktop" rules in a media-query. Based on your mobile media-query, I would suggest `@media screen and (min-width: 416px) {}`
- Change the order in which you put these rules in your CSS file. If you move the whole "mobile" part at the bottom of your stylesheet, they are the ones being considered the latest, overruling similar rules defined earlier

Of course you can also combine both if you wish, but the first one alone will already be doing the trick. I usually don't like relying too much on the position of rules in the CSS  file for it to work, as it's too much subject to change...